# Fullcalendar: Can we use multiple resources for different views

Tags: fullcalendar

I have 2 views in fullcalendar (Day and Week  view). My question is that can we use 2 different resources for day and week view, that means both views uses different json for drawing  events in calendar.

Answer (score 0):

Here my suggestion:

```
 $('#your-selector').fullCalendar({
    viewDisplay: function(view) {

        if (view.title=='agendaWeek') //or whatever view you are using
        {
            $('#your-selector').fullCalendar( 'removeEventSource', DaySource );
            $('#your-selector').fullCalendar( 'addEventSource', WeekSource ); 
        }else{
            $('#your-selector').fullCalendar( 'removeEventSource', WeekSource );
            $('#your-selector').fullCalendar( 'addEventSource', DaySource ); 
        }

    }
});
```

I don't really know if the event viewDisplay is the most appropriate event, probably you need to store the current view in order to avoid overhead and useless requests (**viewDisplay is going to be called when you change the date, for example**. Not necessarily when you change the view). There is a method called changeView (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/views/changeView/) if you wish to have more control over the change views.

Regards,